# Is there any software or app to search for similar melodies?

Tags: audio-software

Artists from my country used to copy popular English songs. They reproduce the whole tune exactly the same as original but sing in the local language. It's sad but true.

I just want to know which popular song they've copied. Is there any software or app to detect similar melodies?

I've tried with many apps such as Soundhound, Shazam, trackID, but they track the exact ID instead of tracking similar melodies. For example, if I load my country artist's song into the trackID app, it doesn't detect the original English song at all. Probably, when they reproduce the original English song, the sound sources become different and trackID app doesn't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Musipedia's "melody search", at https://www.musipedia.org/, where you can use a few different methods to provide the melody in question (keyboard, "contour", microphone).

The quality of results can vary pretty widely, but it's worth a try.